# How do you switch the root view controller of UINavigationController when signing out the user (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uinavigationcontroller, swift5

I am trying to make it so that my initial root view controller is the `HomeViewController`. Then I run a code to check if the user (I am using Firebase) is logged on already. If the user is not logged on, then the root view controller will change to the `LoginViewController` and modally present the Login/Register screens and then release those VCs once the user has signed in.

```
func authenticateUserConfigureView() {

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController)
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else{
        configureViewComponents()
    }

}
```

it seems like if I write the code `rootViewController: LoginViewController` this error shows up

> Cannot convert value of type 'LoginViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Alternatively, If I write `LoginViewController()` then although it seems like the user gets directed to the Login view controller, the simulator immediately crashes.

*UPDATE*

I tried using

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

but nothing seems to happen at all (though it seems to run). I am using the main storyboard to create my view controllers by the way.

Comment: `Alternatively, If I write LoginViewController() then although it seems like the user gets directed to the Login view controller, the simulator immediately crashes.`

What is the crash message?

Comment: It says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT but also highlights my IBOutlets saying Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. The weird part is, my code ran perfectly until I tried to change the root view controller from the log in page to the home page

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to solve, you need pass an ViewController **instance**, you can get from your Login StoryBoard, this way:

```
    let loginViewController = UIStoryboard (name: "LoginStoryboardName", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController )
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = navController
```

To work, in **Login storyboard**, your viewController needs to be set to **InitialViewController**.

If your Storyboard already has a NavigationController, you can just pass the ViewController **instance** to the rootViewController, this way:

```
    let viewController = UIStoryboard (name: "LoginStoryboardName", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say "LoginStoryboardName" do you mean the StoryboardID? Also, I've changed my function to be this following your answer but the error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` is shown.
        
  `func authenticateUserConfigureView() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            let viewController = UIStoryboard (name: "StartVC", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController()
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
        } else{
            configureViewComponents()
        }  
    }`

Comment: Yes, it's just the name of the storyboard file.

This error occurs when there is an Outlet without reference or informing the incorrect Storyboard Name.

You can check these details on the following website:

https://medium.com/@consbulaquena/fixing-thread-1-signal-sigabrt-error-in-ios-9a50a94368da

If you want, you can upload the code on GitHub for me to analyze.

See you.

Comment: Here is the link to the github. The name for the view controller is "Start VC". However when I do `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = "StartVC"` it doesn't work. Thanks in advance https://github.com/youngjei/udon/releases